# How to get value after decimal point from a double value in C#?

Tags: .net, double

I would like to get the decimal value from a double value.

For example:

```
23.456 ->  0.456
11.23  ->  0.23
```

Could anyone let me know how to do this in C#??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: For `-5.4`, do you expect `0.4` or `0.6`?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you might want to reconsider your accepted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

x - Math.Floor(x);

text to bring up to 30 chars

Comment: This will only give an accurate answer with positive numbers. Math.Truncate would be the correct method to use.

Answer (score 55):

There is no Method in System.Math that specifically does this, but there are two which provide the way to get the integer part of your decimal, depending on how you wish negative decimal numbers to be represented.

`Math.Truncate(n)` will return the number before the decimal point. So, 12.3 would return 12, and -12.3 would return -12. You would then subtract this from your original number.

`n - Math.Truncate(n)` would give 0.3 for both 12.3 and -12.3.

Using similar logic, `Math.Floor(n)` returns the whole number lower than the decimal point, and `Math.Ceiling(n)` returns the whole number higher than the decimal point. You can use these if you wish to use different logic for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Math.Floor(n) worked for me: 

decimal = number - Math.Floor(number)

Comment: @CoachRoebuck Yes, if you are only using positive numbers, Math.Floor will work identically to Math.Truncate. However, Math.Truncate will work correctly for all numbers.

Comment: Positive numbers in my case.

Comment: This is also imprecise for n = 1234567.098.

Answer (score 12):

This is what the modulus operator (%) is for. It gives you the remainer when dividing the first operand by the second. Just divide the number you want the decimal of by 1.

Ex:

```
decimal d = new Decimal(23.456);
d = d % 1;

// d = 0.456
```

[EDIT]

After reading Nellius's comment about my post I tested it out. When using doubles the modulus operator actually returns 0.45599999999999952. My answer is in fact incorrect.

[/EDIT]

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: Using the modulus operator with doubles is imprecise, since doubles are not stored as exact values. You refer to the decimal type in your answer, which would give accurate answers, but the OP asked about doubles.

Answer (score 4):

I use this method when i calculate offsets.

```
double numberToSplit = 4.012308d;
double decimalresult = numberToSplit - (int)numberToSplit; //4.012308 - 4 = 0.012308
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Dim numberToSplit As Double = 4.52121
    Dim decimalresult As Double = numberToSplit - Convert.ToInt64(numberToSplit)
    MsgBox(decimalresult)
```