# how to fetch a value after decimal point from textbox

Tags: winforms

In winforms, how to fetch a value after ., i mean if 15.22 is entered, 22 to be fetched from textbox? i tried with split method but it gives me both 15,22. I would like to fetch either 15 or 22.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtCurrency.Text = "00.00";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] str=txtCurrency.Text.Split('.');
            foreach(string s in str)
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get value after decimal point from a double value in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604980/how-to-get-value-after-decimal-point-from-a-double-value-in-c)

Comment: @AccessDenied That's not duplicate, OP is not having value as floating point /decimal type

Answer (score 0):

`Split` is going to return `string[]` that will contain one more string than the character you're splitting on.  So if you've only got one `.` in the string, the second string in the array will contain what comes after the decimal point.

```
string[] str = txtCurrency.Text.Split('.');
string beforeDecimal = str[0];
string afterDecimal = str[1];  // exception if txtCurrency didnt contain a decimal
```

Comment: Can i write event for keychange after decimal and before decimal?

Comment: Can I trigger any event if keychange after . or before .? i mean if 22 is getting modified or 15 getting modified?

Comment: You can wire a delegate to the textbox's `KeyUp` event, and then inspect what key was just pressed.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup%28v=vs.90%29.aspx