# Get Integer and Fractional part of a decimal number

Tags: c#, floating-point, numbers

Given `X.Y`, I want to get `X` and `Y`.

For instance, given `123.456` I want to get `123` and `456` (**NOT** `0.456`).

I can do the following:

```
decimal num = 123.456M;
decimal integer = Math.Truncate(num);
decimal fractional = num - Math.Truncate(num);    

// integer = 123
// fractional = 0.456   but I want 456
```

[REF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605005)

As above-mentioned, using this method I will get `0.456`, while I need `456`. Sure I can do the following:

```
int fractionalNums = (int)((num - Math.Truncate(num)) * 1000); 

// fracionalNums = 456
```

Additionally, this method requires knowing how many fractional numbers a given decimal number has so that you can multiply to that number (e.g., `123.456` has three, `123.4567` has four, `123.456789` has six, `123.1234567890123456789` has nineteen).

Few points to consider:

- This operation will be executed millions of times; hence, performance is critical (maybe a bit-wise-based solution would do better);
- Precision is critical, and no rounding is acceptable.

---

### NOTE 1

***For performance reasons, I am NOT interested in string manipulation-based approaches.***

---

### NOTE 2

The numbers in my question are of `decimal` type, hence methods that work for only `decimal` types and fail on `float` or `double` (due to floating point precision) are acceptable.

---

### NOTE 3

Two sides of decimal (i.e., integer and fractional parts) can be considered two integers. Hence, `123.000456` is not an expected input; and even if it is given, it is acceptable to split it to `123` and `456` (because *both sides are to be considered integers*).

Comment: As stated, `X` and `Y` would be 3 and 6 for an input of either 3.6 or 3.00006. Thus, `X` and `Y` fail to convey complete information about the input. Is that what you want?

Comment: For what purpose do you want this? There may be a better way to accomplish the ultimate purpose than by splitting a number according to its decimal numeral properties this way.

Comment: You warn: "For performance reasons, I am NOT interested in ANY string manipulation-based approaches; please do not recommend such a method.". But note that such an approach may be lot *faster* than a pure numeric approach to turn 0.xyz in xyz.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The system that produces the numbers never generates numbers like 3.000...0006. However, even if it generates, it is totally fine to consider 3 & 6 regardless of the number being 3.6 or 3.0006.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, because that has two drawbacks: (a) a X-digit number stored in 64bit object is represented by a X*8 bit string object (bigger memory consumption and footprint), and (2) instead of 1-2 operations/comparisons you would do on a number, you would need X char comparison and one iteration. It might be saftly neglectable in small-scale applications, but in my challenge, this operation will be used millions (or even billions) of times, which has to reply in ~5sec on a common laptop.

Comment: @Hamed: If the number of fractional digits differs, you must first determine how many. That takes time: several decimal multiplications or divisions (and note that decimal is not a hardware supported type!), which cost much more than a few character comparisons. Try it: I am pretty sure that simple string handling is much faster, especially if there are many fractional digits. The "bigger memory consumption" argument is bogus: the strings can be discarded once used.

Comment: I can store ~30 digits in 64bit using decimal, but the same number of digits would require at least 30*8= 240bits when represented as string (an array of chars). Of course the space will be freed once the variable is an _orphan_ on the heap, but when you take it to the scale I am talking about, then allocating this (tiny) size and freeing it up (memory footprint), is a considerable burden.

Comment: A temporary object of just 240 bits ought to be allocated on the stack. Its allocation would then be part of the existing stack frame allocation, so it would have zero performance cost. You should not preclude classes of answers that experts may find. What you should do is explain the context of the question more fully, as I requested earlier. After many years of working on performance, I can tell you the circumstances in which an optimization desired often offer considerable opportunities for optimization that are not apparent in an isolated portion of the problem stated generally.

Comment: If the C# `decimal` object is `123.4560` instead of `123.456`, do you want 4560 as a result or 456?

Comment: Good point, I want `4560`.

Comment: I just with the our sys. architects, and they confirm `4560`, but mention that the system generating these numbers by definition never generates a number ending with zero. So, `4560`, `45600`, and etc. are not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal has a 96 bit mantissa, so a *long* is not good enough to get every possible value.

Define all (positive) powers of 10 defined for *Decimal*:

```
decimal mults[] = {1M, 1e1M, 1e2M, 1e3M, <insert rest here>, 1e27M, 1e28M};
```

Then, inside the loop you need to get the scale (the power of 10 by which the "mantissa" is *divided* to get the nominal value of the decimal):

```
int[] bits = Decimal.GetBits(n);
int scale = (bits[3] >> 16) & 31;               // 567.1234 represented as 5671234 x 10^-4

decimal intPart = (int)n;                       // 567.1234 --> 567
decimal decPart = (n - intPart) * mults[scale]; // 567.1234 --> 0.1234 --> 1234
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to elaborate on why you AND with `31`?

Comment: That is due to the format of a Decimal (this is documented). bits[3] is a 32 bit integer. that contains 16 bits reserved, 5 bits scale, some 10 bits more reserved and as top bit the sign bit. To get the scale, you must get at bits 16..20, so you must shift right by 16 and then mask with 31 (or 0x1F). The scale must have only values in the range 0..28.

Comment: C# Decimal values are not guaranteed to be normalized. 123.456 may be represented with different values of the exponent field, so that this code might produce 456, 4560, 45600, and so on.

Comment: @Eric: There is only one representation for 123.456, i.e. 123456 x 10^-3. But you can also represent 123.4560, as 1234560 x 10^-4. IOW, the number of fractional digits is remembered and kept as much as possible. So, yes, this code might produce values like 456 or 4560 for the decPart. But that is still a lot better than 4560000000000030695446184836328029632568359375, which Double would get you. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: 123.456 is a number. “123.456” and “123.4560” are numerals, which are themselves ways of representing 123.456. Many numbers have multiple representations in C# decimal. Representations of 123.456 in `decimal` include (0, 123456, 3) and (0, 1234560, 4) (where the three numbers indicate the contents of the sign, numeric value, and scaling factor fields of a `decimal`). Those encodings represent the same value, 123.456, so, yes, 123.456 does have multiple representations. Those representations also convey what Microsoft calls “trailing zeros”, but those do not affect the value.

Comment: 123.4560 is a number too. <shrug>

Answer (score 6):

`BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(num)[3])[2];` - number of digits after comma

```
long[] tens = new long[] {1, 10, 100, 1000, ...};

decimal num = 123.456M;
int iPart = (int)num;
decimal dPart = num - iPart;
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(num)[3])[2];

long pow = tens[count];

Console.WriteLine(iPart);
Console.WriteLine((long)(dPart * pow));
```

Comment: One for the different perspective.

Comment: Instead of the loop, you can do this: `int y = (int)(dPart * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, count));`

Comment: While this works, I have performance concerns as it takes `25.725` seconds on my pc for 100M iterations (which is average number of times this operation will be performed). So, I would appreciate if someone can suggest a more performant solution.

Comment: @Hamed `Math.Pow` has worse perfomance. Also, you can store 10, 100, 1000... in array, and do not waste time at all

Comment: I think storing them in an array is a better.

Comment: @Backs I found that based on IEEE 754 standard this idea won't work for double or float (because they don't have a scale byte). am I right? if so then the only solution to using your method for double or float variables would be cast the var to decimal. or I making a mistake?

Comment: @MohamadArmoon: Of course IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats have scaling. The whole point of floating-point is that the point floats, meaning that there is a scale. The problem with applying your request to binary floating-point would be that most “decimal” numbers like “123.456” are not represented in binary floating-point. For example, in the IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format, the closest representable value is 123.45600128173828125. So it would be impossible to input 123.456 in a binary floating-point format.

Comment: @MohamadArmoon: That also illustrates a reason people may be suspicious of yur question. 123.456 and 123.4560000000001 are very close mathematically, yet they produce very different outputs. That suggests you are doing something that does not make sense in many contexts.

Comment: @MohamadArmoon my solution only works with decimal type

Comment: @MohamadArmoon I highlighted that the number is always `decimal` (this type is chosen exactly for such precision issues).

Comment: @EricPostpischil If Thanks for such a great explanation

Comment: @Eric: the C# decimal type is a 128 bit type consisting of 96 bit "mantissa", 5 bit scale (0..28) and sign bit. It is much like BigDecimal in Java, but not unlimited precision. 123.456 is stored as 123456 x 10^-3 (scale 3), while 123.4560 is stored as 1234560 x 10^-4.(scale 4)

Comment: This should work if you change all longs to decimals, also in the array.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: What are you commenting on? My first comment answered a question about IEEE 754, not C# decimal. My second comment addressed a principal about the mathematics using a hypothetical example, also not C# decimal.

Comment: This question is about C# decimal, however.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: That is why I posted the the first comment addressing an issue OP asked about in a comment as a comment and not as an answer to a question it does not address. The OP specifically asked about IEEE 754 in a comment, so I gave them information about IEEE 754. And the comment about two close numbers mathematically is informative about the `decimal` situation even though the example it uses might not fit in its width. If you need a `decimal` example that makes the same point, just change 123.4560000000001 to 123.45601.

Comment: @Eric: Decimal can have up to 28 significant digits. So no need to make it less precise. It just has a very small range (7.9e28 .. 1e-28).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Then I ask again what are you commenting on? My first comment answered OP’s explicit question about IEEE 754. The second pointed out an issue in the main question. So what was your comment beginning “the C# decimal type” commenting on, and why—what was its intended import?

Comment: Some of your remarks, e.g. "123.456 and 123.4560000000001 are very close mathematically, yet they produce very different outputs. That suggests you are doing something that does not make sense in many contexts". **With decimals, that makes perfect sense**.

Answer (score -5):

The easiest way is probably to convert the number to string.
Then take the substring after the decimal point, and convert it back to int.

Comment: The question specifically says `For performance reasons, I am NOT interested in string manipulation-based approaches.`

Comment: And add to that, the decimal point is locale-specific.